# How to make the Form 2 and three animate while the buttons are on form 1

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, animation, sprite

I want my form 2 and 3 to animate while the buttons are on form 1 and when it goes to form 2 it doesn't stop it continues animating.

**FORM 1 CODE**:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private runSequence() As Image
    Private walkSequence() As Image
    Private idleSequence() As Image
    Private runIndex As Integer = -1
    Private walkIndex As Integer = -1
    Private idleIndex As Integer = -1
    Private WithEvents trmRun As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Private WithEvents trmWalk As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Private WithEvents trmIdle As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form2.PictureBox1.Visible = False
        Form3.PictureBox1.Visible = False
        Form2.Show()
        Form3.Show()
        Me.Width = 300
        Form2.Width = 300
        Form3.Width = 300
        Me.Height = 300
        Form2.Height = 300
        Form3.Height = 300
        Me.Location = New Point(100, 100)
        Form2.Location = New Point(385, 100)
        Form3.Location = New Point(670, 100)
        runSequence = {My.Resources.sonic1, My.Resources.sonic2,
            My.Resources.sonic3, My.Resources.sonic4}
        walkSequence = {My.Resources.SONICWALK1_removebg_preview, My.Resources.SONICWALK2_removebg_preview,
            My.Resources.SONICWALK3_removebg_preview, My.Resources.SONICWALK4_removebg_preview,
            My.Resources.SONICWALK5_removebg_preview, My.Resources.SONICWALK6_removebg_preview,
            My.Resources.SONICWALK7_removebg_preview, My.Resources.SONICWALK8_removebg_preview}
        idleSequence = {My.Resources.SONICIDLE1_removebg_preview, My.Resources.SONICIDLE2_removebg_preview,
            My.Resources.SONICIDLE3_removebg_preview, My.Resources.SONICIDLE4_removebg_preview,
            My.Resources.SONICIDLE5_removebg_preview, My.Resources.SONICIDLE6_removebg_preview,
            My.Resources.SONICIDLE7_removebg_preview, My.Resources.SONICIDLE8_removebg_preview,
            My.Resources.SONICIDLE9_removebg_preview}

        trmRun.Interval = 100
        trmRun.Enabled = False
        trmWalk.Interval = 100
        trmWalk.Enabled = False
        trmIdle.Interval = 170
        trmIdle.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnRUN_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRUN.Click
        trmWalk.Stop()
        trmRun.Start()
        trmIdle.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnWALK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnWALK.Click
        trmRun.Stop()
        trmWalk.Start()
        trmIdle.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub trmRun_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles trmRun.Tick
        runIndex = runIndex + 1
        PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Left + 6
        If runIndex = runSequence.Length Then
            runIndex = 0
            Timer1.Stop()
            Timer2.Start()
        End If
        PictureBox1.Image = runSequence(runIndex)
    End Sub

    Private Sub trmWalk_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles trmWalk.Tick
        walkIndex = walkIndex + 1
        PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Left + 4
        If walkIndex = walkSequence.Length Then
            walkIndex = 0
            Timer1.Stop()
            Timer2.Start()
        End If
        PictureBox1.Image = walkSequence(walkIndex)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnIDLE_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnIDLE.Click
        trmRun.Stop()
        trmWalk.Stop()
        trmIdle.Start()
        Timer2.Stop()
    End Sub
    Private Sub trmIdle_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles trmIdle.Tick
        idleIndex = idleIndex + 1
        If idleIndex = idleSequence.Length Then
            idleIndex = 0
        End If
        PictureBox1.Image = idleSequence(idleIndex)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        If PictureBox1.Left >= 275 Then
            Timer2.Stop()
            Form2.PictureBox1.Visible = True
            Form2.Timer1.Start()

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The thing is I want it to animate on form 2 and 3 without having to put buttons on form 2 and three I want the sprite to be controlled from buttons on the form 1. And I want it to be like if I pressed run on form 1 before it goes to form 2 the continuing animation will be run or walk if I pressed walk before.
Video Example of the current project:
https://youtu.be/DLb68CXy0dI

Comment: I'm a little lost on exactly where you're stuck.  Isn't this just a case of making the animation methods on Form2 and Form3 public so they can be called from Form1?

Comment: ohh how do I do that?

Comment: Well to make a private method public, you just replace the key word Private with Public.  However, I fell you've got some other more deep seated issues here.  In your sample is Form2 and Form3 you've referenced actually instances of these forms or the Default instance?  I suspect the latter, if so you will want to create an instance of each of these forms within form1, then you will have access to their public methods.  For more help, maybe see how your classmate got on when he asked the same question a few days back

Comment: Can you provide code on how to do that?

Comment: Or do I just make all "Private" Statements public?

Comment: And I think my code is broken because even though I deleted the buttons on form 2 design when I use debug it's still there? I think my code is broken. Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: Also when I add other things to the forms designs it doesnt add in debug mode i think its actually broken.